# Duplicate records in DB by condition with changing single value

Tags: mysql, sql

My `nav_item` table looks like this:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+------+-----+
| id | nav_id | active | name   | link | ... |
+----+--------+--------+--------+------+-----+
| 1  |    1   |    1   | Item 1 | .......... |
| 2  |    2   |    1   | Item 2 | .......... |
| 3  |    1   |    1   | Item 3 | .......... |
| 4  |    3   |    1   | Item 4 | .......... |
| 5  |    1   |    1   | Item 5 | .......... |
+----+--------+--------+--------+------+-----+
```

My goal is to duplicate all records having `nav_id = 1`. So this command will do the magic: `insert into nav_item select * from nav_item where nav_id=1;`

**BUT:** I don't want all of them to have `nav_id` same. So all new clones should have `nav_id` for example `4`. But how can I duplicate all of them and also change their `nav_id` to anything I want with a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
INSERT INTO nav_item
    SELECT      NULL,
                4,
                active,
                name,
                link,
                ...
        FROM    nav_item
        WHERE   nav_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;)

```
insert into nav_item
select (t.id, t.nav_id, t.active, t.name, t.link, ...)
from (
    select nav_item.id, @nav_id := @nav_id + 1 as nav_id, nav_item.active, nav_item.name, nav_item.link, ...information_schema.
    from nav_item join (select @nav_id := (select max(nav_id) from nav_item) tmp) where nav_item.nav_id = 1
) t
```